# Facebook doesn't show map on ios

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

i try to show map using facebook opengraph.
So I have a facebook story
[image]

And object type with property
[image]

In my code I create Object

```
            var properties:NSDictionary = ["og:type": "myplanetnamespace:plan", "og:title": "Share on Facebook выа", "og:description": "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.",
           "myplanetnamespace:geoplace:latitude": String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.plan.venue!.location.latitude),
           "myplanetnamespace:geoplace:longitude": String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.plan.venue!.location.longitude) ]
        var object:FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

And Action

```
    var action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
    action.actionType = "myplanetnamespace:create_plan"
     action.setObject(object, forKey: "plan")
```

And content

```
    var content:FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "plan"
```

And than dialog

```
 var shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
        shareDialog.fromViewController = self
        shareDialog.shareContent = content
        if ( shareDialog.canShow() == true ){
            shareDialog.show()
        }
        var error:NSError?
        if(!shareDialog.validateWithError(&error)){
            print ("error")
        }
```

I set location property as required, and there no errors on it. I tried to make a post, but it create it without any maps =((

Answer (score 0):

Where is `geoplace` coming from? That's not part of the Facebook Open Graph, is it? Can you do something like this:

```
[openGraphObject setObject:@{@"latitude": String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.plan.venue!.location.latitude), 
                         @"longitude": String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.plan.venue!.location.longitude)]}
             forKey:@"location"];
```